# R Markdown will not knit file to HTML (though it used to in the past)

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have tried to knit two different R Markdown files in R Studio, either to HTML or PDF and neither seems to work. I have to mention that:
I run Manjaro Linux and I have installed R & R Studio and haven't ran onto any problem so far.
All the necessary packages seem to be already installed in my laptop.
One out of the two files I tried to knit (each one separately) used to knit without problem about two months ago.
Each time I try to knit any of the files I get the following error message:

> processing file: lab_markdown.Rmd
> Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
> unable to load shared object '/home/iason/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
> libicui18n.so.67: cannot open shared object file: Δεν υπάρχει τέτοιο αρχείο ή κατάλογος
> Calls:  ... namespaceImport -> loadNamespace -> library.dynam -> dyn.load
> Execution halted

Does anyone have a clue about what goes wrong?

(By the way, "Δεν υπάρχει τέτοιο αρχείο ή κατάλογος" means "There is no such file or directory".)

Comment: Maybe try reinstalling `stringi`. Try running `install.packages("stringi")` and see if you can do `library(stringi)` without an error afterward.

Comment: @MrFlick I tried it and now it works! Thank you! :)